# Problem deleting records in my database with laravel 7.0

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I'm working on a project using laravel version 7.0, my concern is that when I want to delete images I've inserted in my database, it can retrieve the id of the image to be deleted. The problem is that the deletion does not succeed I receive a blank page and the image in question is not deleted.

CONTROLLER :

```
public function galerie_destroy($id) 
{
     if(Galeries::destroy($id))
      {
        return back();
      }
}
```

ROUTES :

```
/* Delete galeries */
Route::get('/{id}', 'AdminController@galerie_destroy');
```

BLADE :

```
      <tbody>
       @foreach($galeries as $galerie)
        <tr>
         <td>
           <center>
             <img src="{{ asset('galeries_images/'.$galerie->images)}}" class="table-user-thumb" 
                 alt="" style="width:100px; height:100px">
           </center>
         </td>
         <td style="color:black; font-size:1.3em;">{{$galerie->titre}}</td>
         <td style="color:black; font-size:1.3em;">{{$galerie->desc}}</td>
         <td style="color:black; font-size:1.3em;">{{$galerie->created_at}}</td>
         <td>
          <div class="table-actions">
           <center>
            <a href="#" style="color:black; font-size:1.3em;"><i class="ik ik-edit-2"></i></a>
            <a href='/{{ $galerie->id }}' style="color:red"><i class="ik ik-trash-2"></i></a>
           </center>
          </div>
         </td>
        </tr>
       @endforeach                                 
      </tbody>
```

Comment: By default, Laravel use Singular number for making a model, are you sure  your model  is `Galeries`?

Comment: `return back()` doesen't make sense after Gallery has been deleted since that `:id` doesn't exist anymore. Use `return redirect()->route('galleries');` or somewhere appropriate. Wether it solve or not your current issue, you should write and execute this how I wrote here. To debug your issue you can use try catch block and log any error from catch block. Also before any code you should set your environment with xdebug.

Answer (score 0):

Root URI is for your index? So change it :

```
Route::get('galerie/delete/{id}', 'AdminController@galerie_destroy');
```

Controller :

```
public function galerie_destroy($id) 
{
     $data = Galeries::findOrFail($id); // if $id not exist on the table,  it will throw a 404 error page
     $data->delete();
     return back();
}
```

Blade :

```
<a href='/galerie/delete/{{ $galerie->id }}' style="color:red"><i class="ik ik-trash-2"></i></a>
```

Comment: @DiarraKalifala I was in the process of leaving a comment on your deleted answer, but please use the upvote arrow and check mark to properly thank this user for their time. It rewards them with reputation, while a comment doesn't (although it's still nice, but if you're going to comment, also upvote)

Comment: @Diarra please accept this answer as **accepted** ✅, if it really helped

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-model-binding) to type-hint the Eloquent model.

No need to route to a Controller action - you already know the ID exists as you're looping through them.

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('galerie/delete/{Galerie}', function(App\Galerie $galerie) {
    $galerie->delete();
    return back()->with('success', 204);
});
```

**your-view.blade.php**

```
<a href='/galerie/delete/{{ $galerie->id }}' style="color:red"><i class="ik ik-trash-2"></i></a>
```